# Server isn't responding to pings routed via vpn

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, openvpn, proxmox

I've server and virtual machine on it. I'm hosting OpenVPN on this server. The virtual machine has two interfaces: ens18 - for public IP, ens19 - for an internal network. I'm trying to ping 10.2.0.3 (virtual machine ip on ens19) via VPN, but it's not responding. When I run `tcpdump -i ens19 icmp` on the virtual machine, its returning this:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens19, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:50:25.931910 IP 10.8.0.2 > 10.2.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 80, length 40
16:50:29.381784 IP 10.8.0.2 > 10.2.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 81, length 40
```

Ping output:

```
Pinging 10.2.0.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Machine tcpdump output:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
15:58:15.007090 IP 10.8.0.2 > 10.2.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 45, length 40
```

My iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2806K packets, 1097M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 198K   27M ACCEPT     udp  --  vmbr0  any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:[my openvn port]
   40  2429 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 197K   16M ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   vmbr0   anywhere             anywhere            
 177K  336M ACCEPT     all  --  vmbr0  tun0    anywhere             anywhere            
   45  2540 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     10.8.0.0/24          10.2.0.3            
    2   104 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     10.8.0.0/24          10.2.0.0/24         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3102K packets, 1303M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    tun0    anywhere             anywhere
```

My route table:

```
default via [my public ip] dev vmbr0 proto kernel onlink 
10.2.0.0/24 dev vmbr1 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.0.1 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
[my public ip] dev vmbr0 proto kernel scope link src [my gateway]
```

Ip rule list:

```
0:      from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

If you need some extra information, add a comment.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: can you also edit the `tcpdump` command with complete command you used to capture the packets?

Comment: @Karthik on vpn machine: `tcpdump -i tun0 icmp` 
on virtual machine: `tcpdump -i ens19 icmp`

Comment: thanks, just a quick guess, `rp_filter` can cause similar issues when we route traffic via tunnel. may be try disabling `rp_filter` and check the issue?

Comment: @Karthik i have to disable it on vpn machine or on virtual machine? and for what interface?

Comment: Try disabling the rp_filter for the interface `ens19` in the virtual machine bearing `10.2.0.3`

Comment: @Karthik it was already disabled for all interfaces, but i enabled it for ens19, but still virtual machine isn't responding

Comment: If you haven't, please try **disabling** `rp_filter` of `ens19` and check the issue. If it didn't resolve the issue, please try disable/enable the interface `ens19`.

Comment: @Karthik yes, I've disabled it, but nothing happens, disabling and enabling doesn't helps

Comment: Does the VM even have a route for `10.8.0.0/24` (via `10.2.0.1`)? Also please paste `iptables-save` instead. Also make sure you have a route that lead traffics for `10.2.0.0/24` to the tunnel on the VPN client (if you are not using a `redirect-gateway` / `0.0.0.0/0` route).

Comment: Thanks @uQlel. Could you check if the ping response is disabled in kernel by `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`?

Comment: @Karthik It returns 0. Ping works from ens18 as well, and ping works from vpn machine to virtual machine's ens19

Comment: @TomYan How to create this route? I'm newbie at networking

Comment: Run `ip r add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.2.0.1` on the VM. For the VPN part, either add `route 10.2.0.0 255.255.255.0` to the client conf, or, add `push "route 10.2.0.0 255.255.255.0"` to the server conf, assuming you are using `client` / `pull` on the client conf. Note that these route are not *necessary* if both the VM(s) and the VPN clients use the server as their default gateway.

Comment: @uQlel Btw, what does `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` return on the server?

Comment: Also, could you run `tcpdump -ni any icmp host 10.8.0.2` and share the output? And please ping `10.2.0.3` from within the local machine.

Comment: @TomYan THX, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By @TomYan

> Run ip r add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.2.0.1 on the VM. For the VPN part,
> either add route 10.2.0.0 255.255.255.0 to the client conf, or, add
> push "route 10.2.0.0 255.255.255.0" to the server conf, assuming you
> are using client / pull on the client conf. Note that these route are
> not necessary if both the VM(s) and the VPN clients use the server as
> their default gateway